# Disable the close key

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to ensure that the user is forced to use my close key embedded on the form in the database when wishing to exit to ensure that a routine is executed.  I believe i currently have issues because the close key (marked by an 'x') in the top right hand corner of the database offers the user to bypass my exit key.  Is it possible to remove that key so the user is 'forced' to exit using my way?

Comment: In the Form design, you can disable the Close Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a TempVar like this:

```vb
Application.TempVars.Add "blnEnableClose", False
```

... but ensure it runs as soon as possible when your Access project is opened. E.g. if you've got a form that's set to open automatically when your Access project is opened, then put it on that form's Open event.

You can then run the following `IF` statement off every form's Unload event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    If _
        Application.TempVars!blnEnableClose = False _
    Then

        Cancel = True

    Else

        ' optional:
        ' DoCmd.Quit 

    End If

End Sub
```

You can also have the option to set `Application.TempVars!blnEnableClose = True` somewhere else in your project should you want the user to be able to use the standard Access quit button.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXDi8r0AMfU

Comment: Matt, perhaps I wasnt clear in my explanation. I understand how to disactivate the close button on each form, but that doesn't hide the general close button in the top right which i think is just a general close button for MS Access..  Also, what advantage does using your code have to simply setting in the properties of each form 'close button' to no ?

Comment: I think @Matt Hall understood quite clearly, just take a look at what he's done. What his code does is preventing your form to close unless the global variable is set to true (presumably by your Key), it has nothing to do with disabling buttons. I think this solution is brilliant.

Comment: The close button in the form property is just the close button for that form, not Access as a whole. I'm not aware of a way you can programmatically remove Access' close button. What my code does is simply cancel the attempt to unload the form, which is what happens when you try to close Access using its close button.. the effect keeps Access open rather than closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Add the following code to every form module: `Public blnAllowClose As Boolean`.
2. Create a blank form, make sure it starts automatically (using VBA or `AutoExec` macro) and open it as hidden.
3. Add the following code to the `Unload` event of the blank form: `Cancel = Not blnAllowClose`.
4. Add the following code to forms that you want the exit button/command to be allowed: `blnAllowClose = True`.